# Edit foreign key table with asp.net mvc and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-key-relationship, editorfor

I have a entity Kajak:

```
public class Kajak
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        [Key]
        public int KajakID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<KajakImage> KajakImages { get; set; } 
    }
```

Which has a 1 to many relationship to KajakImages:

```
public class KajakImage
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public int FK_KajakID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FK_KajakID")]
    public Kajak Kajak { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create an edit view, where it is possible to do edit both in the same window.

I can't really wrap my head around it. So far I have come to this:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int kajakID)
    {
        Kajak kajak = _kajakRepository.Kajaks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.KajakID == kajakID);
        return View(kajak);
    }
```

But I have no idea on how to creater the "editorfor" kajakimages.

```
@model Timskajakker.Domain.Entities.Kajak
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Redigér kajak</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "AdminKajak"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    foreach (var kajakImage in Model.KajakImages)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KajakImages.Name) // doesn't work.. what to do here?? 
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Gem" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Fortryd og vend tilbage", "Index")
}
```

I am using asp.net mvc 4 and Entity Framework.

I would like to create an edit option for the Kajak properties except id and the name property from all attached kajakimages

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to create a custom [EditorTemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx). You have to create a partial view file with the name `KajakImage.cshtml` (must be the name of the model to be rendered) in a folder called `EditorTemplates` under `Views/YourControllerName` (or in a `Shared` folder):

```razor
@model Timskajakker.Domain.Entities.KajakImage

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ImageID)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

And then just render this template in your `Kajak` edit view by using:

```razor
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "AdminKajak"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KajakImages)

    <input type="submit" value="Gem" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Fortryd og vend tilbage", "Index")
}
```

You don't need to write a `foreach` loop because ASP.MVC will render the partial view once per item automatically when you pass in a collection of `KajakImage`s.

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ImageID)` is here to ensure that you get `KajakImage` objects instantiated by the model binder on post request which have the correct original key value set together with the `Name` property. (The remaining properties of the `KajakImage` collection will be invalid/empty/`null` because you don't have form fields for them in your view.)